# Making a subprocess.call for a command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran the script through online checker, formatted it completely. I want it to run as follows:

```
script.py --i smth
```

it executes subprocess.call and defines strings from raw_input.

i believe subprocess.call SED is wrong. The original command is `sed -i 's/#include "martini.itp"/#include "martini_v2.1-dna.itp"\n#include "martini_v2.0_ions.itp"/' cg-1rna.top`

```
import getopt
import sys
import subprocess

inputfile = ''
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "v", ["ifile"])
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-i", "-sfile"):
            inputfile = arg
    subprocess.call(["grep", "-v", "HETATM", "rna.pdb", ">", "aa-1rna.pdb"])
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "editconf", "-f", "aa-1rna.pdb", "-o", "aa-1rna.gro"])
    subprocess.call(["python", "martinize-nucleotide.py", "-type", inputfile, "-f", "aa-1rna.gro", "-o", "cg-1rna.top", "-x", "cg-1rna.pdb"])
    subprocess.call(["cp", "cg-1rna.top", "cg-1rna.top.bak"])
    subprocess.call(["sed", "-i", "'s/#include", '"martini.itp"/#include', '"martini_v2.1-dna.itp"\n#include#', '"martini_v2.0_ions.itp"/', "cg-1rna.top"])
    subprocess.call(["vmd", "cg-1rna.pdb"])
    dvalue = raw_input("Cancel script using CTRL+C or write the distance between the first and last nucleotide with a total of 4 decimals (in nm): ")
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "editconf", "-f", "cg-1rna.pdb", "-d", dvalue, "-bt", "dodecahedron", "-o", "box.gro"])
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "solvate", "-cp", "box.gro", "-cs", "water.gro", "-o", "bw.gro"])
    subprocess.call(["vmd", "bw.gro"])
    wvalue = raw_input("Cancel script using CTRL+C or write the number of water molecules added: ")
    subprocess.call(["printf", '"\nW', "        ", wvalue + '"', ">>", "cg-1rna.top"])
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "grompp", "-f", "em.mdp", "-c", "bw.gro", "-p", "cg-1rna.top", "-o", "01-em"])
    nnvalue = raw_input("Warning: Last input step! Cancel script using CTRL+C or write the number of sodium ions to be added: ")
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "genion", "-s", "01-em.tpr", "-o", "bw.gro", "-p", "cg-1rna.top", "-pname", "NA", "-nname NA", "-nn", nnvalue])
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "mdrun", "-v", "-deffnm", "01-eq"])
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "grompp", "-f", "equil.mdp", "-c", "01-em.gro", "-p", "cg-1rna.top", "-o", "02-eq", "-maxwarn 1"])
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "mdrun", "-v", "-deffnm", "02-eq"])
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "grompp", "-f", "mdrun.mdp", "-c", "02-eq.gro", "-p", "cg-1rna.top", "-o", "output"])
    subprocess.call(["gmx", "mdrun", "-v", "-deffnm", "output"])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print "rnascript.py --i <networkmodeltype>"
sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: What do you believe the call is wrong? What is it doing, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: look at " and '. Are they ok?

Comment: i also get errors for commands not running properly. `grep -v HETATM rna.pdb > aa-1rna.pdb` is not run as it should be in subprocess.call

Comment: yep will fix this when i have time. busy asf atm. two projects and exams.

Answer (score 1):

Each argument to `subprocess.call` should be a separate shell argument.

This would be one shell argument:

`'s/#include "martini.itp"/#include "martini_v2.1-dna.itp"\n#include "martini_v2.0_ions.itp"/'`

You have split it internally at whitespace:

```
subprocess.call(["sed", "-i", "'s/#include", '"martini.itp"/#include', '"martini_v2.1-dna.itp"\n#include#', '"martini_v2.0_ions.itp"/', "cg-1rna.top"])
```

When `sed` receives these several arguments, it will probably not know what to do and error out.  Do you see an error?  I would recommend reading it and including it in your question next time.

Try sending that single shell argument as a single argument to `subprocess.call`, perhaps like this:

```
subprocess.call(["sed", "-i", 's/#include "martini.itp"/#include "martini_v2.1-dna.itp"\n#include "martini_v2.0_ions.itp"/', "cg-1rna.top"])
```